# Hide statusBar for new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a full screen application (no status bar) which eventually needs to open an Intent using an external library. I'm aware of 'traditional' ways to hide status bar, but can't figure out how to achieve it when there's no `Activity` declared on `AndroidManifest.xml` nor I have access to Activity `onCreate` method.

This is how I open my `Intent`.-

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent(ScanIntent.SCAN_ACTION);
intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

intentScan.putExtra("scan_mode", ScanIntent.SCAN_MODE_RESULT_AS_URI);       
this.startActivityForResult(intentScan, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_SCAN);
```

When this activity is started, the statusBar appears, but I'd like to keep it hidden. Is it possible?

Comment: The Activity is declared in the AndroidManifest for the application that contains it.  Otherwise you would not be able to start it. Is the external library defined as an Application?  Do you have access to it's manifest?

Comment: Thanks @Dale. The external lib is a jar, no access to manifest :(

Comment: Is the library only available as `jar`? If you can access the library's `.java` files, make the appropriate changes, repackage it into a `jar` file, and include it in your project. This can only work if the library's license allows you to edit it.

Comment: @vikram, I don't think source code is available. What about extending `ScanIntent` overriding `onCreate`? May it work?